# Problems using Bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, csv

I have a project that I need to do a massive data load from a CSV file generated by an application. The structure of CSV file is as follows:

```
indice;hora;puerta;num;nombre;departamento;departamento;id usuario;estado;tarjeta
"0001";"05:51:56";"Parqueadero";"0046";"Rafael Iglesia";"ADMINISTRATIVOS";"Dep2_00";"9229926977";"(M11)Acceso Normal";"04756:22242"
"0002";"05:53:19";"Parqueadero";"0036";"Orlinda Torres";"ADMINISTRATIVOS";"Dep2_00";"4326087729";"(M11)Acceso Normal";"04246:24075"
```

As you can see, the first row doesn't use quoted identifiers (""), whereas the next row does. As such, I tried to do a bulk insert (using SQL Server 2017) with `FIRSTROW=2` and the result is:

```
0 rows affected()
```

Conversely, if I use this method without `FIRSTROW`, SQL obviously can't process the file. Is there a way to process this data while skipping the first row?

This is the table I'm inserting into:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEMPORAL_IV] (
  [id_temp_dia] int NULL,
  [hora_temp] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
  [puerta_temp] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
  [id_tar_temp] int NULL,
  [usuario_temp] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
  [desc_dep_temp] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
  [id_dep_temp] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
  [doc_usu_temp] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
  [mensaje_temp] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
  [num_tar_us_temp] [nvarchar](15) NULL
)
```

And here's the bulk insert command:

```sql
BULK INSERT TEMPORAL_IV 
FROM '\\argos\informatica$\temp\datos.csv' 
WITH (fieldterminator=';',FIRSTROW=2);
```

Is there an alternative?

Comment: Check the row terminator in the file. The default row terminator for `BULK INSERT` is `\r\n` (windows newline) - if your file uses another row terminator (for example just `\r` or just `\n`) and you don't specify an alternative with the `rowterminator` option, `BULK INSERT` will treat the whole file as one line - this would fit with the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: I was trying with rowterminator and still not works, I tried with \n, \r and \n\r and not works. Here the sintax: `BULK INSERT TEMPORAL_IV from '\\argos\informatica$\temp\datos.csv' with (fieldterminator=';',ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',FIRSTROW=2);`

Comment: What row terminator does your file use?

Comment: I see the problem, thanks for help me, On the program that I created to export data to CSV, I've an error, the method isn't use the row terminator that I'm using. Thanks to help me.